# Ошибка "_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" в MySQL в Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Я учу MySQL в Python и хотел добавить значения в базе данных, но все время получал ошибку

> ```
> _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Commands out of sync; you can't run 
>     this command now.
> ```

Я пытался решить проблему с помощью других ответов, но они мне не помогли

Вот код:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from config import data_base_config


def create_connection_mysql_data_base(
        db_host="127.0.0.1",
        user_name="root",
        user_password="Ali-Muhammad385",
        data_base_name=None
):
    connection_data_base = None
    try:
        connection_data_base = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=db_host,
            user=user_name,
            password=user_password,
            database=data_base_name
        )
        print("Data base connection was successfully")
    except Error as data_base_connection_error:
        print(f"Data base connection was failed {data_base_connection_error}")
    return connection_data_base


try:
    connection = create_connection_mysql_data_base(
        data_base_config["mysql"]["host"],
        data_base_config["mysql"]["user"],
        data_base_config["mysql"]["password"],
        "Application_Users"
    )
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    create_data_base_SQL_query = """
    USE Application_Users;
    INSERT INTO users
    VALUES ("James", "Smith", "1997-10-02", "James89375Smith492",
    "mail", "JamesSmith285@gmail.com", "James89375Smith492", 222-457);"""
    cursor.execute(create_data_base_SQL_query)
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
except Error as data_base_error:
    print(f"Error {data_base_error}")
```

РЕДАКТИРОВАННО: меня попросили добавить полный текст ошибки

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
>   File "C:\Users\777\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\QuizApp\data_base\main_data_base.py", 
>         line 40, in <module>
>     connection.commit()  
>   File "C:\Users\777\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\QuizApp\venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py",
>         line 511, in commit
>     self._cmysql.commit()  
>   _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Commands out of sync; you can't run 
>         this command now
> ```

Comment: На какой строке ошибка возникает? Добавьте в вопрос полный стек-трейс ошибки.

Comment: @CrazyElf готово

Comment: я не знаю почему ее там нет, сейчас добавлю. теперь есть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалите строку (№ 35)

```
USE Application_Users;
```

т.к. ваше `connection` уже связано с этой датабазой:

```
connection = create_connection_mysql_data_base(
    data_base_config["mysql"]["host"],
    data_base_config["mysql"]["user"],
    data_base_config["mysql"]["password"],
    "Application_Users"                         # здесь
```

Comment: огромное вам спасибо. вот реально от души. БаракАллаху Фикум!!!

Comment: @Али-МухаммадЗакарьяев, не стоит, я очень рад, что вам помогло. Ва фике баракаЛлах!